# python find string pattern and extract data

Tags: python, string, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract date and time (**mm/dd/yyyy XYZ**) from the following string:

"ABC is expected* to report earnings on **mm/dd/yyyy XYZ**."

This is usually the first sentence of that particular paragraph if it helps.

**ABC** can be any combination of numeric and string values.

**XYZ** can be one of: "before market open", or "after market close", or simply an empty value "".

I can probably just do a search on the string to check if it contains keywords "before" or "after", but I really want to learn how to more effectively extract the **mm/dd/yyyy XYZ** part out of the string.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code

Comment: you should start with regex.

Comment: You can do this pretty easily with regular expressions